# How get back losts archive_ids of AWS Glacier vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I am new to AWS Glacier and was having a work around with it. I created a new vault and upload around 2-3 files (Using boto API) to it but didn't saved the archive-id given back. Later I got to know that they were necessary to delete the archhives and then-and-then we can delete the vault.

I looked into the boto documentation but couldn't find any method which gives back the archive-ids of the files uploaded. Is their any different way in which I can get them or directly delete the vault.

Answer (score 0):

It was a later addition to Glacier, despite being what I would think as pretty important functionality.  The process is you post a job which is by the "initiate-job" operation, similar to how you would do a retrieval.  This process is simply a POST to /AccountId/vaults/VaultName/jobs, but the SDKs and CLI make it much easier!

The distinction between downloading an archive and downloading the inventory is the type if 'inventory-retrieval' rather than 'archive-retrieval' as you'd do if you were bringing one item back from Glacier.

This first link is how you'd do it with the CLI, but you'll need the second link to make some sense of what to put in the JSON-formatted body.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-initiate-job-post.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glacier/initiate-job.html